# How to modify the "x" of the fraction to the same size of the first one?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fontsize

Here is a screenshot from a `beamer` file. I want to change the "x" of the fraction to the same size of the first "x". Anyone can help?

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt]{beamer} 
%\usecolortheme[named=Plum]{structure} 
%\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
%\setbeamerfont{title}



%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\usepackage{CJKspace}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym,bm,amsmath,amssymb}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\mode <presentation>

%\title[TINLPN]{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
%\author[赵]{赵moumou \\ \texttt{euclid@123.com}}
%\date[ISPN'80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}


%%
\title{专题Largest Prime Number}
\author[赵]{赵moumou \\ \texttt{euclid@tokoyo.edu}}
\institute[UMBC]{UMBCdjskfljadfl}
\date[2013-07-09]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
%%
%%第一个frame
\begin{frame}



\titlepage
\end{frame}


%第二个frame
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame名称}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}


%About Section and Subsection
%\section{Motivation}
%\subsection{The Basic Problem That We Studied}


%%第三个frame%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{What Are Prime Numbers?}      

   \begin{definition}
    A \alert{prime number} is a number that has exactly two divisors.
   \end{definition}
    \pause
  \begin{exampleblock} {例子}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 2 is prime (two divisors: 1 and 2).
      \pause
    \item 3 is prime (two divisors: 1 and 3).
      \pause
    \item 4 is not prime (\alert{three} divisors: 1, 2, and 4).
    \end{itemize}
   \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

%%第四个frame%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
例题：\\
\small{$f'(x)=3x+89$}
已知$g(x)=x+\tfrac{1}{x}-lnx$\\好题
\end{frame}

\end{CJK}
\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$g(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\ln x$`

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, `\tfrac` enforces the fraction to be in `\textstyle` (actually, you are using `\textstyle` here anyway due to the use of inline math with `$`).

Either use a display-style environment like `equation` or `gather` from the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package or use `\dfrac` if you want to use inline math anyway.

In the code below I have used both variations. Unfortunately, the Chinese characters do not show up on my machine.

### Code

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{latexsym,bm,amsmath,amssymb}
\mode <presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\begin{frame}[t]
例题：
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=3x+89
\end{equation}
已知:
\begin{equation}
 g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}-\ln x
\end{equation}
好题
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
例题：
$f'(x)=3x+89$ 已知 $g(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\ln x$
好题
\end{frame}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]